# Proof that line is edge of convex hull

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I have 2 questions about convex hulls (in 2D only):

[Convex hull example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47eZv.png)

In the picture above, I have a blue curve AB defined by X & Y coordinates. The convex hull of AB is computed with Matlab and shown in red.

1. My first question - is there an analytical way to calculate the coordinates of points C & D from the blue curve AB? Line CD is the edge of the convex hull and C and D are the points which first intersect line AB. In the picture above, I have identified the coordinates of C & D by manually inspecting the data in Matlab. Alternatively, I could have identified C & D by comparing the coordinates of line AB and the convex hull by brute force. But is there a smarter mathematical approach?
2. My second question - in the reverse scenario, let's say I am given the coordinates of points C & D. How can I mathematically prove that line CD is the edge of the convex hull of AB?

I am new to the idea of convex hulls. I understand visually what it means (stretching a rubber band over the data points), but mathematically, this is new to me.

Thanks in advance for any help!

The following is the code used to generate the picture above in Matlab.

```
X = [-50 1:1:100]';
Y = [0;13.02;22.58;29.82;35.44;39.88;43.44;46.34;48.72;50.70;52.36;53.77;54.96;55.98;56.86;57.62;58.29;58.87;59.39;59.86;60.27;60.65;61;61.32;61.62;61.90;62.17;62.43;62.68;62.92;63.16;63.40;63.64;63.88;64.12;64.36;64.61;64.87;65.13;65.40;65.67;65.96;66.25;66.55;66.87;67.19;67.52;67.87;68.22;68.59;68.97;69.36;69.77;70.19;70.62;71.07;71.53;72.01;72.50;73;73.53;74.06;74.62;75.19;75.78;76.38;77;77.64;78.30;78.98;79.68;80.39;81.13;81.88;82.66;83.46;84.28;85.12;85.98;86.87;87.78;88.71;89.67;90.65;91.66;92.69;93.75;94.84;95.95;97.09;98.26;99.46;100.69;101.95;103.24;104.56;105.92;107.31;108.73;110.18;111.67];

conv_hull_area = convhull(X,Y);

plot(X,Y,'LineWidth',1.5);
hold on
plot(X(conv_hull_area),Y(conv_hull_area),'--','LineWidth',1.5)
plot([1 81],[13.02 88.71],'gX:','LineWidth',1)
hold off
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
hleg=legend('Curve AB','Convex hull of AB','Line CD');
```

Comment: It looks like a piecewise-smooth curve, and $C$ is the only non-smooth point, which can be found just by evaluating the function at the end of a "piece". The harder part is finding $D$. To do that, given the curve $(x,y)=f(t)$ going from $C$ to $B$, find the values of $t$ such that $(f(t)-C)\wedge f'(t)=0$, or equivalently $\det[f(t)-C,\,f'(t)]=0$. In other words, find when the tangent line hits the endpoint $C$ (or $A$ or $B$).

Comment: @mr_e_man, thanks for your reply.
May I know how you obtain the equations (f(t)−C)∧f′(t)=0, and det[f(t)−C,f′(t)]=0 ?

Comment: The first formula uses exterior algebra, and the second formula uses the determinant of a matrix: $\det[(a,b),(c,d)]=ad-bc$. This is $0$ when the two vectors $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are parallel to each other. -- Do you know about parametric curves, and derivatives? I've assumed you do.

Comment: @mr_e_man, many thanks for your explanation.

In my example, C is non-smooth on the line AB, while D is smooth as you've mentioned. If both C and D are smooth, then the way to calculate C & D I presume would be evaluate a tangent line orignating from C and another one originating from D, and check if they overlap.

But let's say I don't know beforehand if C and D are smooth or non-smooth. Could your solution be generalized to such a scenario?

Comment: What kind of data are you starting with? If you have parametric equations, then a smooth point is where the derivative $f'(t)$ exists; this is usually easy to check. If you have just a finite list of points, then the convex hull is a polygon, and talking about curves is misleading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this specific example, the C to B section of the curve was generated using a parametric equation, but in general, my future curves would be a list of data points. That's why in the Matlab code above, I opted to show a list of data points (X & Y) instead of an equation Y=f(X).